# Is Shyriiwook still the name of the Wookiee language in Disney canon?

Tags: star-wars, languages, canon

I'm reading the novelization of *The Force Awakens*, and the word "Shyriiwook" doesn't appear in the text.  Instead, the book refers to it solely as "the Wookiee language".

Is "Shyriiwook" still the canonical name of the language spoken by Wookiees?

Comment: It most likely means the writer didn't know there WAS a name. Disney probably hasn't set a lot of guideline standards. They got rid of what was in place and didn't standardize anything yet.

Comment: @Thaddeus - in general, what you said may have merit. In case of TFA novelization, the writer is Alan Dean Foster. He LITERALLY wrote the book on Star Wars. As in, The book "Star Wars". The novelization of Episode IV. While it's not impossible that he didn't know... I find it somewhat unlikely.

Comment: So he couldn't be bothered in other words.

Comment: @Thaddeus - Not to mention, I'd be floored if LSG didn't vet the Official Novelization.

Comment: @Thaddeus - I assumed that it was either noncanonical now, or it wasn't deemed to be the kind of information that the casual reader should be expected to know.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, absolutely it is.**

It's directly mentioned in the [Star Wars: Lost Stars](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lost_Stars) novel, a part of the new "Journey to the Force Awakens" series

> *Thane believed she was too trusting, but it was her ship and her
> business. She’d run a freighter for a couple of centuries without his
> help, so he figured she could size people up well enough. **As he’d
> learned to understand Shyriiwook better, he’d realized how intelligent
> his captain was.***

---

This is backed up in [Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know)

> *3 Wookiee Languages: Shyriiwook, Thykarann, Xaczik*

along with a handy *translation guide* offering some useful phrases to memorise:

> **How to speak Shyriiwook**
>
> "WYAAAAAA!" = "Hello!"
> "AARRR WGH GGWAH" = "Jump to hyperspace"
> "ROOOARRGH UR ROO" = "I have a bad feeling about this"
> "WWWAH RRROOOAAAH WHA?" = "Want to play some holo-chess?"

Comment: haha that translation guide is priceless

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Actually there's a little more. I was debating whether to bother adding it, but since you've mentioned it...

Comment: I think the length of your answer is perfect as it is, and a good comedian knows how not to belabour a joke :) Good things come in threes etc.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

> The three Wookiee languages are Shyriiwook, Thykarann and Xaczik.
>
> *(src: Sun's "[20 fun facts from new book Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need To Know](http://www.thesun.co.uk/sol/homepage/features/6651132/Twenty-fun-facts-from-the-new-Star-Wars-trivia-book.html)")*