# Are any Star Wars languages fully developed and learnable?

Tags: star-wars, languages

*[This is a generalization of [Josh B.'s question]](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/176518/44632)*

Star Trek's *Klingon*, Game of Throne's *Dothraki* and *High Valyrian*, Tolkien's *Elvish*, *Dwarvish*, and even *the black speech*, and more, are fully developed languages that you can learn to speak if you <s>have way too much time on your hands</s> are curious enough.

Are any languages in the Star Wars universe similarly developed to the point that you can learn to speak them?

*(Josh B.'s original question was about Shyriiwook and translating un-subtitled dialog by Chewie, but I'll open it up to any language with on-screen spoken dialog)*

Comment: Does Aurabesh count?

Comment: @Valorum In that all spoken Aurebesh bears a striking resemblance to English? Sneaky sneaky.

Comment: Pooh-chah hee, Solo. Gooka-kawa Wookie. Heh heh heh.

Comment: I’m now waiting for a huttese Duolingo course like Klingon and high Valyrian

Comment: Nien Nunb speaks [Kikuyu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kikuyu_language#In_popular_culture), a real-world language masquerading as an alien language.  Not what you meant, I'm sure, so not a proper answer, but technically it meets the criteria of being fully developed and learnable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**. The most complete language realised in the Star Wars (canon) universe is Huttese, comprising [**around 500(ish) words and phrases**](http://www.completewermosguide.com/hutttranscript.html). Theoretically that should be enough to form [the basis of a spoken language](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2015/07/toki-pona-smallest-language/398363/) but since it was never written *as a language* it's simply not consistent enough to be used every day.

Other in-universe languages such as [**Ewok**](http://www.completewermosguide.com/ewokese.html), [**Shyriiwook**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114177/is-shyriiwook-still-the-name-of-the-wookiee-language-in-disney-canon) and [**Jawa 
 Trade Talk**](http://www.completewermosguide.com/jawaese.html) have at most a few dozen words and phrases, again not enough to be used under all but the most rarified of circumstances.

---

For completeness, I should point out that spoken [**Galactic Basic**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Basic) can be learned with relative ease.

Comment: I am surprised there isn't more about [binary](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Binary). R2 had so many lines beeping.

Comment: @bdecaf - Ironically, he was speaking Galactic Basic throughout. It's just that he uses so many swearwords that they had to bleep out everything he said.

Comment: Really, really disgusting dialogue?

Comment: @chepner - Yes. And that's actually [canon](https://mlpnk72yciwc.i.optimole.com/cqhiHLc-SpBJWOtK/w:600/h:628/q:90/http://www.bleedingcool.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/STWARS2015013-int3-3-9aa04-e1449061997577.jpg), believe it or not

Answer (score 2):

The Sullustese spoken by Nien Nunb in Return of the Jedi is actually the Tanzanian language of Haya. The language was burrowed and ironically when the film was viewed in Tanzania, the Hayan people were very delighted the words had credible dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Mando’a is the only one that I’ve been able to find that comes so close to a fully learnable language. I believe it is enough for daily conversation. The words and their definitions can be found on http://mandoa.org/.

Aurebesh is a direct stand in for the English alphabet and a few combinations of letters, you can find it with a quick google search.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! Please be aware that this is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum, so your request for a Huttese library needs to be posted as a separate question.... except you don't need to, because Valorum already linked to one in his answer from 2 1/2 years ago.

Comment: Mandoa has about a thousand words (which is respectable for a conlang), but almost all of them are nouns or verbs, not to mention quite a few words-as-phrases. There's pretty much nothing you could use as an *actual* language